# How to set a default function for an object?

Tags: javascript, function, object

So, I've started playing with using an object to help organize my functions. So instead of having to make super long function names, I can just have sub functions in an object with the same prefix.

In my example, I'm using 'get' as a prefix, so I could call subfunctions by doing `get.function();` and `get.otherfunction();`. However, I want to also be able to set a "default" function for the `get` object, so I can just call `get();` by itself and it runs a function (but I don't want that function to run if I'm calling one of the subfunctions).

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
var get = {
    default: function() {
        alert('default function');
    },
    secondary: function() {
        alert('secondary function');
    }
}
```

Comment: In EMCAScript terms, you want an object that implements the `[[Call]]` internal property. `Function` is the only native object type that is callable, so you'll need to make your object a function.

Comment: You are not using an `Array` anywhere. { } is an **object literal**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to make an ordinary function, then add other functions as properties:

```
var get = function() { ... };

get.secondary = function() { ... };
```

If you want to, you could also write

```
get.default = get;
```

Or

```
get.default = function() { return get(); };
```

Comment: awesome, I didn't think to try it that way :P

Comment: though, the one downside to this method is having to retype the function prefix each time I define a sub function, I was trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII You could easily make an IIFE and loop through an object, setting properties of the final function: http://jsfiddle.net/XYFVc/

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree I mean, I don't have a huge problem with retyping get for each function definition, however I prefer to minimize things that could cause errors as much as possible. Like, if I had a much longer prefix, my chances of making a typo are much greater if I have to repeat that prefix every time I'm declaring a new function definition; I also feel like it would be more difficult to detect a typo in a declaration than it is to detect one when you call the function.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: JSHint will catch any typos you make.  You can use `$.extend()` or an equivalent to avoid repeating the name.

Comment: @Ian I wouldn't call your example "easy". Its not very eye pleasing either.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII It's "easy" in the sense that all you have to do is declare an object literal, and then loop over it. How isn't that "easy"? And it's unfortunate you think it isn't very "eye pleasing", because it's quite a common way to enclose specific code

Comment: @SLaks I don't think it would catch a typo in this scenario though:

`ger.subfunction = function(){};`

it wouldn't say that I misspelled get, because it would just assume `ger` is already an object, or it would create it on the fly.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII It would say `ger` is not defined...unless you already defined it somewhere else

Comment: @Ian, ah, I do see that it catches that.

Comment: @Slaks what is `$.extend()`?

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/  http://lodash.com/docs#assign

Comment: @SLaks is lodash a framework too? I don't use jQuery or any framework.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: How do you define framework? Why do you insist on re-inventing wheel?

Comment: @SLaks I'm not "re-inventing [the] wheel", I'm making my own wheel. I just want the code I need for my purposes. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: Then you can write your own `extend()`.  It's a very useful pattern (like the rest of Lodash)

Comment: @SLaks but, it doesn't seem to cut down on the amount of stuff to type. In fact, it seems to increase it.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: `var get = $.extend(function() {...}, { secondary: ..., thingy: ... })` You only need to type `get` once.